# calculate quantity multiply unit price input and equal input will be subtotal and sum all subtotals

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to calculate quantity multiply unit price inputs and equal input will be subtotal and sum all subtotals...

I used this code in javascript, and it is working fine, but in table didn't work.

Please help.

HTML/PHP:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-name="cont-table">
    <thead style="">
        <tr>
            <th class="check-this"><input class="check_all" type="checkbox" onclick="select_all()"/></th>
            <th class="text-center"> م </th>
            <th class="text-center"> اسم الصنف </th>
            <th class="text-center"> الوحدة </th>
            <th class="text-center"> الكمية </th>
            <th class="text-center"> سعر الوحدة </th>
            <th class="text-center"> العام المالي </th>
            <th class="text-center"> إجمالي قيمة الصنف </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="case"/></td>
        <td><span id="snum">1.</span></td>
        <td><!--<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name[]"/>!-->
        <select class="select" id="first_name" name="first_name[]">
            <?php
                $stmt = $db->query("SELECT first_name6 FROM item");
                //$stmt = $pdo->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<option >" . $row['first_name6'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select></td>
        <td><!--<input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name[]"/>!-->
        <select class="select" id="first_name" name="first_name[]">
            <?php
                $stmt = $db->query("SELECT first_name7 FROM unit");
                //$stmt = $pdo->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<option >" . $row['first_name7'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select></td>
        <td><input class="select qty" type="number" id="tamil" name="tamil[]"/></td>
        <td><input class="select unit" type="number" id="english" name="english[]" /></td>
        <td><!--<input type="text" id="computer" name="computer[]"/>!-->
        <select class="select " id="first_name" name="first_name[]">
            <?php
                $stmt = $db->query("SELECT first_name8 FROM financial");
                //$stmt = $pdo->execute();
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<option >" . $row['first_name8'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="total" class="amount" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="add_row"  type="button" class="delete btn btn-default pull-right">مسح</button>
<button id="add_row" style="margin-right:5px;" type="button" class="addmore btn btn-default pull-right">اضاف صنف</button>
<br>
<br>
<h3 class="table-h3 " style="text-align:center;">اجمالي قيمة العقد</h3>
<input type="text" name="totalprice" class="result" value="" />
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
$(".qty").on('input', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var unitVal = self.next().val();
    self.next().next().val(unitVal * self.val());
    fnAlltotal();
});
$(".unit").on('input', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var qtyVal = self.prev().val();
    self.next().val(qtyVal * self.val());
    fnAlltotal();
});
function fnAlltotal(){
    var total=0
    $(".amount").each(function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this).val()||0);
    });
    $(".result").val(total);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is not attaching event handlers to any of the `input` elements that do not exist yet, but only to the single pair of text `input`s  that exists at page load.

When you add rows, the `input` event on those new `input` elements will not be captured. To achieve that, you should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Secondly, your `input` elements are all single children of their parent `td` elements, so when you apply the `next` method on them, it will not return anything.

Instead, you could retrieve the table row the event is being triggered on and then read the values from both the `.unit` and `.qty` inputs in that row to then update the `.amount` element in that same row:

```
// Use event delegation to capture events on rows that will only exist in future
$(document).on('input', '.qty, .unit', function (e) { // get event
    // get number of row this event is occurring in:
    var row = $(e.target).closest('tr').index();
    // get both unit and qty from that row:
    var unitVal = $('.unit').eq(row).val(); 
    var qtyVal = $('.qty').eq(row).val(); 
    // update the amount in that row:
    $('.amount').eq(row).val(unitVal * qtyVal);
    // adapt total (no change to your code)
    fnAlltotal();
});
```

Comment: yes its really this code helped more instead of above  when i add row in table, many thanks..

Comment: hello, after check i have in each row in table columm for delete row, if i delete row the result not calculated is still the same number.. i need to update the result input when i delete row .. help please

Comment: Just call `fnTotal` when user clicks on "Delete" button.

Comment: sorry, how to make it this thecode for delete:
$(".delete").on('click', function() {
 $('.case:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
    $('.check_all').prop("checked", false); 
 check();

});

Comment: That is really a different question. Please post it as a new question. If you want, you can post the link to that new question here, and I will have a look at it then.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the code below, the `input` has no `next`:

```
<td><input class="select qty" type="number" id="tamil" name="tamil[]"/></td>
```

It is alone in the `td` element.

See [next() in jQUery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/next/), it says:

> .next()
>
> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

And as I said earlier, the `input` element in question has no siblings, it is alone...

So, when you run...

```
self.next()
```

It selects nothing, and thus...

```
self.next().val()
```

Returns `undefined`.

A similar problem exists on the code using `prev`.

---

It at all possible access these fields by `id`, if you need to have multiple instances of these fields in the page, I would suggest to generate ids form them with PHP.

---

Working example using classes (the HTML is made of fragments of the OP):

```js
$(".qty").on('input', compute);
$(".unit").on('input', compute);
function compute()
{
  // // if there is only one element with those classes
  // var qtyVal = $(".qty").val();
  // var unitVal = $(".unit").val();
  // // otherwise...
  
  // get the tr that contains the element that triggered the event
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
  var qtyVal = tr.find(".qty").val(); // find .qty within that tr
  var unitVal = tr.find(".unit").val(); // find .unit within that tr
  
  // check for when the input aren't found
  if (typeof qtyVal == "undefined" || typeof unitVal == "undefined")
  {
    // leave the function
    return;
  }
  
  // write amount

  // // if there is only one element with those classes
  // $(".amount").val(qtyVal * unitVal);
  // // otherwise...

  tr.find(".amount").val(qtyVal * unitVal);

  // call fnAlltotal
  fnAlltotal();
}
function fnAlltotal(){
    var total=0
    $(".amount").each(function(){
        total += parseFloat($(this).val()||0);
    });
    $(".result").val(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
 <td><input class="select qty" type="number" id="tamil" name="tamil[]"/></td>
 <td><input class="select unit" type="number" id="english" name="english[]" /></td>
 <td><!--<input type="text" id="computer" name="computer[]"/>!-->
 <select class="select " id="first_name" name="first_name[]">
  <!-- PHP generated code -->
 </select></td>
 <td><input type="text" id="total" class="amount" value="" /></td>
</tr></table>
<!-- later -->
<input type="text" name="totalprice" class="result" value="" />
```

Comment: thanks for useful answer, but im searching for funtions uses classes inputs because id its changed when i add raw in table.. this table editor with add, delete rows... can we modify that functions with uses class ?

Comment: @PeterAzer will there always be a single element with that class? If so, then yes you can do it with classes, just be explicit. That is, select the elements directly instead of going with `prev` and `next`. Otherwise, you will need to use [`parent`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`children`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) to go up and down the DOM tree. Edit using [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) as [trincot suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40061695/402022) may work too.

Comment: im sorry, im beginning javascript could you write me the code please ?